# How connect to docker container from another computer in local network

Tags: docker

I have running docker container on one computer (in this container I start tomcat and mysql server) and want connect to this container from another computer in local network. How I can this do?

Comment: This example (and from official docs)  work if using version docker 18.0.9 ( on one my macbook I have "docker for mac" and if I run app here,  I don't have any problems,  but if I run my app on old macbook,  where did install "docker toolbox", I can't get access to container where running tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 0.0.0.0:80:80 image
```

or

```
docker run -it --rm --network host image
```

The second option will expose everything inside a container, you can read about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). I would not advise to use it, except for test purposes.

The first option will attach 80 port on the host system to 80 port inside the container. You can read about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

Please, before asking such questions, read the official [manual](https://docs.docker.com/network/)